# Generic filter for ActiveMQ to consume message based on filter

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-classic

I have 2 microservices - service A and service B. For service A there is one pod running, and for service B there are two pods. Service A publishes messages on an ActiveMQ, and service B consumes it.

There are two pods for service B so I want to have a generic filter so that pod 1 of Service B consumes the message based on the given generic filter and pod 2 consumes the messages based on the given generic filter.

For Example, there is a userId in the payload and if the userId is even then I want pod 1 to consume and userId is odd then I want pod 2 to consume.

Can any one let me know that how to do this.

Comment: The message would have a header and payload so the payload has userId.

Comment: You can't filter based on payload. You can only filter based on message headers & properties.

Comment: I know we can use selector but here we have the same service just running on the 2 pods so if I use selector then also it's the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I got your point but while publishing the message I can set the property even or odd by checking the user id.

Comment: If both pods will be running the exact same application I don't think there's anything you can do from an application perspective to split the messages up like you want. Why not simply let the broker decide which consumer gets each message?

Comment: Yepp, I understand that but I wanted to have control over this also, so can you think of any solution or maybe something out of the box.

Comment: Why do you want control over it? I already indicated what possibilities I can think of for application control here (i.e. none).

Answer (score 0):

I understand how you could have a use case for this scenario. You can use a [destinationInterceptor](https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations) to perform a broker-side filter using a selector. I don't generally recommend this, since it generally requires a broker restart to make changes to the filtering rules.

If load traffic load is medium (less than 10M messages per day and/or less ~300 msg/s peak) you can readily use a Camel route to filter traffic using a content-based-router pattern (CBR) and support making changes to the filter rules (ie.. a new userId is added or one is removed).

producer -> queue://PRE.SORT -> Camel route CBR consumes

Then the Camel route doing CBR produces messages in the queue(s) based on the userId values
queue://PODA.IDS
queue://PODB.IDS
etc..

NOTE: Camel is very capable of handling over 10M messages a day and 300 msg/s. I'm providing these 'medium' sizing metrics as a guideline to where you can set it up quickly and not worry too much about performance tuning, etc.